# Python NumPy - How to print array not displaying full set

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm converting a list into a NumPy array:

```
a = np.array(l) # Where l is the list of data 
return a
```

But whenever I go to print this array:

```
print (a)
```

I only get a slice of the array:

> [-0.00750732 -0.00741577 -0.00778198 ...,  0.00222778  0.00219727
>    -0.00048828]

However, If I print the size, I get the actual size of the array: `61238` Could anyone have a guess to where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the summarization options with [`set_printoptions`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html#numpy.set_printoptions)

```
np.set_printoptions(threshold = your_threshold)
```

The threshold parameter sets:

> Total number of array elements which trigger summarization rather than
>   full repr (default 1000).

But do you really want to print a huge array?

Answer (score 2):

It's just for the reason of usability. If you have an array of size 10^100 and you try to print it - that would take a long-long time. So, that's why it's printed like this, like "that is that exact array that is starts from X and ends with Y". To print the whole array just print every element in a for-loop :)

Comment: Well you just made me look stupid..;) Thank you for your help :)